# 404 error when creating new cordova project

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, phonegap

I am getting this error  when trying to create a new cordova project:

```
Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: HTTP error 404 retrieving version 3.6.3 of cordova for www
at Request._callback (/usr/share/cordova-cli/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/lazy_load.js:251:30)
at Request.self.callback (/usr/share/cordova-cli/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/request/request.js:372:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:160:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/share/cordova-cli/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/request/request.js:1310:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:165:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/share/cordova-cli/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/request/request.js:1258:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:165:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

The command I am using to create the project is this:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

I am on ubuntu 16.04.2 and my cordova version is 4.3.1

Any help will be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question and for those stuck maintaining old projects (on cordova 4.3.1) and can't upgrade cordova, this is due to "create" trying to get the "hello world" project from a dead url:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-app-hello-world.git;a=snapshot;h=3.6.3;sf=tgz

To work around this in these older versions create the project with --src which prevents fetching this "hello world" www project:

`cordova create --src=<path-to-your-www> myapp`

Answer (score 2):

@Denis Babineau is correct on this. One more thing I could add is that the passed `--src=` flag needs to point to a local folder and then that will be used to create the app. The link that he added in his comment takes you the repo where you can download the helloworld app of any version you may need, recreate that on your local env and point to that folder with the `--src` parameter and that will produce the app with that particular cordova version.

So something like: `cordova create --src='../helloworld3.5.0/' helloapp com.helloapp.domain helloapp`

Where the helloworld3.5.0 structure is like so:

```
/
index.html
css/index.css
img/logo.png
js/index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

4.3.1 is the old (and probably deprecated) version of Cordova. I think you should update this package:
`sudo npm install -g cordova`

Comment: Hey, yes. I concluded this is related to my operating system which is too old. I will need to start by updating my OS. Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and after following steps it works good for me:

1. update packages (just to be sure, that all is up to date): `sudo npm install -g cordova`
2. reboot your PC

Comment: Hey. I started by doing that and found that it's probably my OS that doesn't support new version of a lot of stuff. Thanks for your answer, it put me on the right path to find the issue.